# Continuous deployment using LFTP gets "stuck" temporarily after about 10 files

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, lftp

I am using GitLab Community Edition and GitLab runner CI setup to deploy (synchronize) a bunch of JSON files on a server using LFTP. This job however, seems to "freeze" for a few minutes every 10 files roughly. Having to synchronize roughly 400 files sometimes, this job simply crashes because it sometimes takes more than an hour to complete. The JSON files are all 1KB. Neither the source and target servers should have any firewalls rate limiting the FTP. Both are hosted at OVH.

The following LFTP command is executed in orer to synchronize everything:

```
lftp -v -c "set sftp:auto-confirm true; open sftp://$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_USER:$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_PASSWORD@$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_HOST:$DEVELOPMENT_DEPLOY_PORT; mirror -Rev ./configuration_files configuration/configuration_files --exclude .* --exclude .*/ --include ./*.json"
```

Job is ran in Docker, using [this](https://github.com/mwienk/docker-lftp) container to deploy everything. What could cause this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We have the exact same issue

Comment: Unfortunately I never figured out what causes the issue. I believe as a workaround I set the timeout to something like 1 second, which gets the job done. @Phillip

Comment: Yeah, I ended up getting around it by lowering the timeout to something very low then also also setting the CI file to retry the job if it fails. This has caused the project to complete. I'll paste my solution below.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you coming from google we had the exact same setup. The way to get LFTP to stop hanging when running in a docker or some other CI you can use this command:

```
lftp -c "set net:timeout 5; set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set ftp:ssl-force yes; set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; open -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $HOST; mirror dist / -Renv --parallel=10"
```

This does several things:

1. It makes it so it won't wait forever or get into a continuous loop
   when it can't do a command. This should speed things along.
2. Makes sure we are using SSL/TLS. If you don't need this remove those
   options.
3. Synchronizes one folder to the new location. The options `-Renv` can
   be explained here: https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html

Lastly in the gitlab CI I set the job to retry if it fails. This will spin up a new docker instance that gets around any open file or connection limitations. The above LFTP command will run again but since we are using the `-n` flag it will only move over the files that were missed on the first job if it doesn't succeed. This gets everything moved over without hassle. You can read more about CI job retrys here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#retry

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. `set net:timeout 5; set net:max-retries 2; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5` has solved an issue where the lftp mirror command gets "stuck" after uploading a large amount of data to an sftp server (Upload of the directory with many large files was successful, but anything downstream was not synced). The lftp would not disappear from the process list until killed manually, probably because the sftp had closed the connection while transfer was active (according to this discussion: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/ftp-hangs-or-breaks-at-or-near-100-completion.57966/).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using `rsync` instead? I'm fairly sure you can benefit from the incremental copying of files as opposed to copying the entire set over each time.